# AutoHotkey: Forward slashes as "q" and reversed parenthesis in CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, automation, macros, autohotkey

I'm running Windows 10 Home Edition, and I've been using AutoHotkey v1.1.23.01 for the past couple of days now. I have the following script:

```
:*:dmenv::
Input, machine,,{Enter}
Send, FOR /f "tokens=*" `%i IN ('docker-machine env --shell=cmd %machine%') DO `%i
return
```

Every time I run this script from within the context of CMD, I receive the following output:

```
FOR qf "tokens=*" %i IN )wdocker-machine env --shell=cmd asdw( DO %i
```

As you can see, the forward slash (`/`) has been replaced by `q`, the parenthesis have been reversed, and single quotes (`'`) have been replaced with `w`.

Can anyone tell what I might be missing here?
I've already tried checking in other programs (ie Notepad++, Explorer etc.), and this script works everywhere except CMD.

I've tried escaping the characters by using the backtick like the AHK documentation suggests, and converting the `.ahk` file to UTF-8 via Notepad++.
Also, I've tried using work-arounds such as `chr(47)` and `Clipboard = code` without any luck.

**Final Note:**

I've just realized that when I change my language to HEB, and write `dmenv` to run the script, it works: `FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell=cmd asdf') DO %i`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keyboard layout isn't English, but cmd.exe is.

If you switch windows' language to English before running `send`, it'll work (note that switching languages can be done by ahk / dll calls)

You can, however, use the following workaround instead: (tested on Win10)

```
:*:dmenv::
Input, machine,,{Enter}
text = FOR /f "tokens=*" `%i IN ('docker-machine env --shell=cmd %machine%') DO `%i
clp_bck := clipboardAll
clipboard := text
send ^v ; use ctrl v to send the text
clipboard := clp_bck
return
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but CMD is not pasting the content of the clipboard. Writing `dmenv` in CMD after updating my script with your suggestion simply outputs: `^v`

Comment: @GSWV Then instead of `^v` use send `{ctrl v}`, or whichever command that triggers a paste command.

Comment: After a little bit of searching based on @2501's response, I found the following format that worked for me in cmd: `send ^{vk56} ; key id used to solve cmd paste issue`.